# Android Application Development

Tags: android

I am using eclipse and brand new to android. I want to know How to print the string entered by the user in EditText column. I am taking the input from the user but i want to use the string entered by the user in my program. How should i do that??

Answer (score 1):

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/07/exercise-hello-world-with-edittext.html

```
EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
CharSequence edit_text_value = edit_text.getText();
```

Comment: This is working fine. Thank You.
but how should i compare the characters of the string "edit_text_value"?? I was trying "edit_text_value[i]=="edit_text_value"[j]"; like this but its not possible as its a char sequence not an array. please help.

Comment: [CharSequence.chatAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt(int))

Comment: Other people here are right that using `toString()` will make your lives easier. (Not really mandated)
String class also has the method `charAt()`.
But there are also a lot of cool functions on the String class that might help you achieve what you want to do without manipulating chars. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

It has to have .toString()

`String strEditText = editText.getText().toString();  // For getting text from EditText`  `System.out.println ( strEditText );   // For Printing`

Comment: i tried 
EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
CharSequence edit_text_value = edit_text.getText();

and This is working fine. Thank You. but how should i compare the characters of the string "edit_text_value"?? I was trying "edit_text_value[i]=="edit_text_value"[j]"; like this but its not possible as its a char sequence not an array. please help.

Comment: @user1188874 - You can use 'edit_text_value.charAt(i)==edit_text_value.charAt(j)'

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple,

```
String strEditText = editText.getText().toString();  // For getting text from EditText
System.out.println ( strEditText );   // For Printing
```

You can also visit [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/481485/Android/Mobile/retrieve-string-EditText) for example of how to retriver EditText's String.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
String strEditText = editText.getText().toString();
System.out.println ( strEditText );
```

now use this strEditText  for using edittext value

Comment: It always gives an error. First line of code gives an error says can't make a reference.

Comment: EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext);         please add this line before these two lines.

Comment: i tried EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message_text); CharSequence edit_text_value = edit_text.getText(); and This is working fine. Thank You. but how should i compare the characters of the string "edit_text_value"?? I was trying "edit_text_value[i]=="edit_text_value"[j]"; like this but its not possible as its a char sequence not an array. please help

Comment: why you compare charsequnce ? use string to compare the Values . ok